# css, html help : float left and right, cutting off background to expand past div

Tags: css, html, css-float, background-color

I have a div floating left and a div floating right, and I would like to have a background-color changed. It changes the background, but it stops right before the floating divs. When I take them off, it continues having the correct background color that I desire.

```
<div style='clear:both;border-bottom:3px solid #999;border-top:#333 solid thin;background:#D7E7E8;position:relative;'>
    <div style='width:1091px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:70px;'>
        <div style='float:left;width:200px;border:thin solid black;margin-bottom:50px;position:relative;'>
            float LEFT
        </div>
        <div style='float:right;border:thin solid black; width:800px;border:thin solid black;margin-bottom:50px;position:relative;'>
            float RIGHT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must clear the floats so the parent can surround them.

```
<div style='clear:both;border-bottom:3px solid #999;border-top:#333 solid thin;background:#D7E7E8;position:relative;'>
    <div style='width:1091px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:70px;'>
        <div style='float:left;width:200px;border:thin solid black;margin-bottom:50px;position:relative;'>
            float LEFT
        </div>
        <div style='float:right;border:thin solid black; width:800px;border:thin solid black;margin-bottom:50px;position:relative;'>
            float RIGHT
        </div>

        <!--HERE IS THE CLEARING DIV: -->
        <div style="clear: left;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also, make the parent itself float, and then you won't need the additional markup (clearing div). If you do this, then your parent will need a width specified.

EXPLANATION:

When an element is floating, the parent is not aware of its height (unless it is a floating element itself). You need a clear below the floats so that the parent div recognises the full height of all its children.

Comment: Thanks! i chose this to be correct answer because I dont have to mess with doctype!! thanks guys!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to force-clear the floats - you need only to define the overflow for any position:relative div. Overflow:hidden and overflow:auto close the div without any further intervention, on everything from IE6 up.

Change the first line to:

```
<div style='clear:both;border-bottom:3px solid #999;border-top:#333 solid thin;background:#D7E7E8;position:relative; overflow:hidden;'>
```

and it'll accomplish the same thing as forcing the div closed.

Comment: I did test it in IE 6.0.2900.2180 (real IE6 under XP, in VirtualBox), and the results are identical with the forced-div version. 


It might be that you forgot your DTD — Don't forget to add:


`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">`

in place of plain old <html>

Comment: doctype is pretty crucial when it comes to browser-rendering

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm pretty much exclusively using the HTML5 doctype these days. +1 for this answer.